# SQS: How to forward message to subscriber based on a certain key

Tags: publish-subscribe, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a validation service which takes in validation-requests and publishes them to a SQS queue. Now based on the type of validation request, I want to forward the message to that specific service.

So basically, I have one producer and multiple consumers, but essentially, one message is to be consumed by only one consumer.

What approach should I use? Should I have a different SQS queue for each service or I can do this using a single queue based on message type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have three options;

1. The first option, like you say is to have a unique consumer for each message type. This is the approach we use and we have thousands of queues and many different messages types.
2. The second option would be to decorate the message being pushed onto SQS with something that would indicate it's desired consume, then have a generic consumer in your application that can forward the message on to the right consumer. Though this approach is generally seen as an anti pattern, I would personally agree.
3. Thirdly, you could take advantage of [SNS filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html) but that's only if you use SNS right now otherwise you'd have to invest in some time to setup it up and make it work.

Hope that helps!